# Bundling multiple existing projects

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I currently have two existing projects, one Node.js and one React. Both in their own folders with their own package.json and node_modules.

I wanted to create a third folder for Electron and bundle the existing projects together. Is this possible or do I need to merge all three projects together and use a single package.json and node_modules?

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience with similar tasks: I'd find a good boilerplate project for that setup, clone the repo and install it. Then I'd study how they did it on the boilerplate and try to structure my own code in a similar way.

The reason for me doing it like that: the boilerplate guys are the true experts and I'm not. They know what they're doing and so their result would be good for me too.

A good candidate would be [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate).